# how to include http and ui bootstrap in angular js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

how to i include `$http` and `ui.bootstrap`.
actually i use `ui.bootstrap` for open the bootstrap modal(open) . on `ng-click`.
after that i want to send all modal data to server, for that i use http in angular contaoller. but it gives error. 
below are my angular js code

```
 var app = angular.module("modalFormApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);``
 app.controller("modalAccountFormController", ['$scope', '$modal','$log', '$http'

  function ($scope, $modal, $log, $http) {

     $scope.showForm = function () {
    $scope.message = "Show Form Button Clicked";
    console.log($scope.message);

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal-form.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        scope: $scope,
        resolve: {
            userForm: function () {
                return $scope.userForm;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};
    }]);


app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$modalInstance',userForm, function($scope, $http, $modalInstance, userForm){   

 //var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance,$http, userForm) {
 $scope.form = {}
 $scope.url = 'submit.php';
 $scope.submitForm = function () {
if ($scope.form.userForm.$valid) {
     $http.post($scope.url, {"name": $scope.name, "email":        

      $scope.email, "message": $scope.message}).
                success(function(data, status) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.status = status;
                    $scope.data = data;
                    $scope.result = data; 
                })  
    //console.log('user form is in scope');
    //$modalInstance.close('closed');
} else {
    console.log('userform is not in scope');
}
};

 $scope.cancel = function () {
$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
 };
   }])
```

i got below error when i inject `$http` in app.controller

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module modalFormApp due
>   to:        [$injector:nomod] Module 'modalFormApp' is not available!
>   You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If
>   registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the
>   second argument.

below my index.html code
                enter code here

```
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Angular Modal Forms</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <style>
            body{ padding-top:30px; }
    </style>

     <!-- JS ===================== -->
     <!-- load angular -->
      <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
       </head>

      <body ng-app="modalFormApp">
     <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

    <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>AngularJS Form Validation</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="modalAccountFormController">
        <div class="page-body">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showForm()">Create                      Account</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you include your index.html

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving means that your modalFormApp module hasn't been loaded properly, and this could be for a few different reasons. However, it is difficult to tell because it seems as though you have many issues in your code.

A couple of things I've noticed by skimming quickly:

Line 1: You have these two apostrophes at the end of the line. What are they for?

Line 2: You're missing a comma after '$http' parameter, at the end of the line, before the callback function.

Try to tidy up your code a bit, and work in smaller increments so that you can quickly catch an error when you create one and have a smaller set of possible causes to discover.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please mark the question as answered as I'm hoping to sometime earn some reputation points :)

Comment: but i can not able to send data to php